# Spring Webflux Mono : unable to collect the results as List

Tags: java, stream, spring-webflux

I am using spring webflux to consume one another servie and trying to aggrigate the results into a list for different input combinations.
But stuck in one point where I couldn't subscribe and convert the results into a List

1. This method will take a Map and iterate through the map and invoke another service ith different input combinations.
   But couldn't proceed in getAPrice() to accomplish what i want :(

   Input:

   ```
    public Mono<List<APrice>> getAPrice() {
           return
                   Mono.create(monoSink ->{
                        getActiveMonths()
                               .entrySet().stream()
                               .flatMap(e->getContractPrice(e.getKey(),e.getValue())
                               /* stuck here, don't have any idea how to subccribe and get the AP Object and collect it as a list */
                   });
       }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   expected : List[APrice]
   ```
2. Above getAPrice() calls the below method which is working fine and returns data for the valid input combinations

   Input:

   ```
    /*Method is Working fine and returns a Mono<APrice> for the right input combination */
   public Mono<APrice> getContractPrice(String key, String value){
       return Mono.create(monoSink ->{
           acServiceWebClient.getPrice(key,value) 
                   .subscribe(aPrice ->  monoSink.success(aPrice),
                           error->{
                               monoSink.error(error);
                           });
       });
   }
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   {
   "id": 11,
   "curveName": "NT",
   "Month": "Mar 2010",
   "price": 160.17,
   "status": "ACTIVE"
   }
   ```

```
    private Map<String,String> getActiveMonths()
    {
        Map hm = new HashMap();
        hm.put("key1","value1")
        hm.put("key2","value2")
        return hm;
    }
```

Looking forward to get some suggestions to complete the getAPrice() in a better way, Also it will be helpful to correct me in case im following a wrong approach.   Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a `MonoSink` for your job. What you can do is create a `Flux` from your `getActiveMonths` `entrySet` and then call the method `getActivePrice` with that `entrySet`'s `key` & `value`. So, your `getAPrice` should actually look like

```java
public Mono<List<APrice>> getAPrice() {

    return Flux.fromIterable(getActiveMonths().entrySet())
        .flatMap(entry -> getContractPrice(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())).collectList();
}
```

There are two reasons to simply create a `Flux` here.

1. You have no reason to create a sequence programmatically (which `MonoSink` or `FluxSink` is primarily used for). You have your data present and you just need to consume it without any manipulation.
2. You actually have a collection and you want to consume each entry of it which makes it a good candidate to be used into a `Flux` (0-n elements) instead of a `Mono` (0-1 elements).

Refer to this official [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.create) documentation which brings in more clarity and proves my point.

If `getContractPrice` returns `Mono<List<APrice>>`? Here's how `getAPrice` should look

```java
public Mono<List<APrice>> getAPrice() {

    return Flux.fromIterable(getActiveMonths().entrySet())
        .flatMap(entry -> getContractPrice(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
        .flatMapIterable(aPrices -> aPrices).collectList();
}
```

Comment: @Ishank, Thanks a lot for your valuable comments.I have made necessary hcanges as per your comments.  Just need to understand, in case getContractPrice returns a Mono<List<APrice>> what  else we need to change here.

Comment: @busywithJava, updated the answer to address your query in the comment.